# localhost keeps redirecting to 0.0.0.0 when navigating to 127.0.0.1:8000 to access laravel

Tags: laravel, docker, localhost

I always used Laravel valet for developing Laravel projects, but i was curios and wanted to try docker for the first time. After a lot of struggle i decided to ga back to Laravel valet, only to find out that the url i used with valet redirects to 0.0.0.0:8080.

`0.0.0.0:8080` was the url docker exposed outside the container.

I removed docker completely from my mac. Stil got the same problem.

I've tried to run php artisan serve, but `127.0.0.1:8000` also redirects to `0.0.0.0:8080`.

I've tried access other Laravel applications with valet, no problem.

With my host file is nothing wrong, and so is my network settings.

Here is my host file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```